# Apache autoindex listing directories but not files

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I've been trying to setup a directory listing for a given directory on the same server (CentOS 7 with Apache httpd 2.4.6-88).
I came across an example to display public domain icons that seems to come with httpd and it works fine.

I tried copying my files next to the icons and it works great =) I can browse my directories and get the files in them.
*The example is under `/usr/share/httpd/icons/` and my files were under `/usr/share/httpd/delivery`*

What I failed to do is list the **files** under `/var/local/delivery` that I created for that purpose.
The whole directory tree is here and I can browse all of them but impossible to show the files in them... I have an empty list at each "leaf" directory in my directory tree where the files should be.

Changing the owner of the directories/files does not seem to have an effect so I ruled out some kind of permissions problem.

Here is the configuration I added to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf`

```
Alias /deliveries/ "/var/local/delivery/"
Alias /deliveries "/var/local/delivery/"

<Directory "/var/local/delivery/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is the `IndexIgnore` line in the same file

```
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
```

What am I missing that "hide" my files *(and not the directories)* **only** when they are under `/usr/share/httpd/delivery` and not under `/var/local/delivery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was missing.
I'm not *extremely* familiar with SELinux but the problem seemed to come from there.

With this command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/local/delivery
```

I changed the SELinux context of my directory to let httpd access it.
I found the solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/720162/814202 after trying to directly access one of the files that I wasn't seeing. Doing so gave me an error

```
access denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

which led me to the askubuntu question.

Hope this helps